# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams android 4.1.2

Tags: android, exception

I have this Exception only on some devices on android 4.1.2. So, I want to know what is the problem it can be.
Here is stack trace - no one line from my code, only from SDK - exception happens in SDK, so no lines were missed:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to 
android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:996)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:576)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15563)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15563)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5112)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15563)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5112)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15563)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5112)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15563)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2003)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1242)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1417)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1135)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4653)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: change `import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;` to `import android.widget.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;`

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: It seems that the params you dynamically set for the view does not match the params type the parent expects

Comment: Your import statement for LayoutParams might be importing ViewGroup.LayoutParams or vice versa ...Please check it once

Comment: error in imports, import view with actionbar.

Comment: There is many thousands of strings of code and I don't where it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are importing `import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams` instead of `android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;`

so Delete `import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;`

and Add `import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;`

Comment: I think you are right, I tried to change my code in this way, but can not check because of I don't have device on android 4.1.2. So, I just accept your answer.